# Django: Editing a manytomany model field referenced by another model through a form

Tags: django, django-forms, many-to-many, field

I am trying to create a model instance that includes a list of model via many-to-many field via ModelForm. However when this occurs, I need to be able to change one of the fields being referenced.

Here is the stripped code:

```
class AllAtt(models.Model):
    weighting = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    mass = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    required_Power = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    memory = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

class Mission(AllAtt):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Scenario(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True,blank=True)
    mission = models.ManyToManyField(Mission)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ScenarioForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Scenario
        fields = ('name','mission',)
```

Where the Missions instances are imported from a database. Currently this allows me to pick Mission instances from the multiplechoicefield, however this isn't what I need. I want to be able to include all of the Mission instances in the Scenario and then change the "weighting" field through the form.

*A simple example of what I am trying to do: 
I have a certain number of tasks (Missions) and when combined they accomplish something (Scenario). 
A human has a lot of task functions. If my Scenario is "Getting ready for a date" then these functions may be weighted in importance as:
Make coffee - 0, Feed dog -2, Shower - 3, Get dressed - 5. Whereas if the Scenario is "Working on Django code" these functions are weighted as: Make coffee - 5, Feed dog - 2, Shower - 0, Get dressed - 1. And each time I make a new Scenario I need to be able to change the weights of all the possible tasks.*

Any help or insight on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you need to specify weight on `Mission` relations in `Scenario`.

Basically what you need is `through` Model (with weight). You can see it documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work for the set up. Any idea on how to get this data displayed in the form?

Comment: I think you should use formsets for "through" fields

Comment: I've got:

WeightFormset = modelformset_factory(Weight, exclude=('scenario',), extra=20,)
 formW = WeightFormset(request.POST or None)

But I can't figure out how to save this data as a Scenario instance